# How do I save my Camera Presets to a text document and load it on startup?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I need code that would enable me to save my camera's presets and load it at the start or maybe when a GUI button is pressed.

```
void savePreset()
{
    //Create a txt file or replace own text file and write into it
    using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter("presets.txt"))
    {
        writetext.Write(player.transform.position.x + ", ");
        writetext.Write(player.transform.position.y + ", ");
        writetext.Write(player.transform.position.z + ", ");
        writetext.Write(player.transform.rotation.w + ", ");
        writetext.Write(player.transform.rotation.x + ", ");
        writetext.Write(player.transform.rotation.y + ", ");
        writetext.Write(player.transform.rotation.z + ", ");
        //Boolean to show that it is still saving
        saving = true;
        writetext.Close();
    }
}
```

This is a rough idea for saving the code onto a text document.
How do I load this info and apply it on my camera?

Comment: Just use `System.Xml.Serialization`. That enables you to easily save and load any object. [See this example here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/saving-and-loading-data-xmlserializer.85925/)

Answer (score 1):

The best approach might be using [PlayPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html), this way you don't need to care about the path of the setting file, and it is also much faster than saving/loading data to and from the files, as in Mac this is saved to plist, and in windows, saved in registry.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

Camera cam;
Transform t;
void Start () {
    cam = Camera.main;
    t = cam.transform;
}
void OnGUI()
{
    if (GUILayout.Button ("Rotate (10,0,0)")) {
        t.Rotate(new Vector3(10,0,0));
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("rX", t.rotation.x); // Save
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("rY", t.rotation.y);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("rZ", t.rotation.z);
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();                                          
    }
    if (GUILayout.Button ("Reload Camera Euler angle")) {

        var x= PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("rX"); // Load
        var y= PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("rY");
        var z= PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("rZ");
        cam.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x,y,z);                       
    }
}
}
```

[image: Original camera]
[image: Changed camera]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out :D
Here's the code for the loadpreset

```
void loadPreset()
 {
  using (var reader = new StreamReader (File.OpenRead ("presets.txt")))
  {
   //while not end of text file
   while (!reader.EndOfStream) 
   {
    //reading each line
    var line = reader.ReadLine ();
    //dividing into values when "," detected
    var values = line.Split (',');

    //if number of values is 16
    if(values.Length == 7)
    {
     //Save the output value based on it's value position
     if (float.TryParse (values [0], NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out tempPos.x)
         && float.TryParse (values [1], NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out tempPos.y)
         && float.TryParse (values [2], NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out tempPos.z)
         && float.TryParse (values [3], NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out tempRot.w)
         && float.TryParse (values [4], NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out tempRot.x)
         && float.TryParse (values [5], NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out tempRot.y)
         && float.TryParse (values [6], NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out tempRot.z)
         )
     {
      //Set the player position and rotation
      player.transform.position = tempPos;
      player.transform.rotation = tempRot;
     }
     else
      continue;
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Thanks to all who tried to help

Answer (score -1):

You can use StreamReader to read your txt file.

```
void Load()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("presets.txt"))
    {
        string[] paras = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');

        Vector3 pos = new Vector3();
        pos.x = float.Parse (paras[0]);
        pos.y = float.Parse (paras[1]);
        pos.z = float.Parse (paras[2]);

        Quaternion q = new Quaternion();
        q.w = float.Parse (paras[3]);
        q.x = float.Parse (paras[4]);
        q.y = float.Parse (paras[5]);
        q.z = float.Parse (paras[6]);

        player.transform.position = pos;
        player.transform.rotation = q;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a best practice. Some *real* serialization would be a better answer.

Comment: sorry, this is not good. I just thought he want to use this method.